# Why is mp.Pool().map() slower than ProcessPoolExecutor().map()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, concurrent.futures

I have this silly code to paraphrase a behavior I encountered at work:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from struct import pack
from time import time


def packer(integer):

    return pack('i', integer)


if __name__=='__main__':

    pool1 = Pool()
    pool2 = ProcessPoolExecutor()

    nums = list(range(10**4))

    start = time()
    res1 = pool1.map(packer, nums)
    print (f'total mp pool: {time() - start}')

    start = time()
    res2 = pool2.map(packer, nums)
    print (f'total futures pool: {time() - start}')

    pool1.close()
```

I get (Python 3.8.1):

```
total mp pool: 0.1600649356842041
total futures pool: 0.9206013679504395
```

At work, I modified code from `mp.Pool()` to `concurrent.futures` to allow moving between processes and threads.

I then found that exception propagation was funky with `concurrent.futures`. Moving back to `mp.Pool()`, saw that I have a performance decrease.

I understand that  `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` is supposed to be a higher level API, how is it faster than `mp.Pool()`?

I see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py) that `ProcessPoolExecutor.map` is simply:

```
super().map(partial(_process_chunk, fn),
                              _get_chunks(*iterables, chunksize=chunksize),
                              timeout=timeout)
```

where `super` is [_base.Executor](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py):

```
def map(self, fn, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1):
    """Returns an iterator equivalent to map(fn, iter).
    Args:
        fn: A callable that will take as many arguments as there are
            passed iterables.
        timeout: The maximum number of seconds to wait. If None, then there
            is no limit on the wait time.
        chunksize: The size of the chunks the iterable will be broken into
            before being passed to a child process. This argument is only
            used by ProcessPoolExecutor; it is ignored by
            ThreadPoolExecutor.
    Returns:
        An iterator equivalent to: map(func, *iterables) but the calls may
        be evaluated out-of-order.
    Raises:
        TimeoutError: If the entire result iterator could not be generated
            before the given timeout.
        Exception: If fn(*args) raises for any values.
    """
    if timeout is not None:
        end_time = timeout + time.monotonic()

    fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]

    # Yield must be hidden in closure so that the futures are submitted
    # before the first iterator value is required.
    def result_iterator():
        try:
            # reverse to keep finishing order
            fs.reverse()
            while fs:
                # Careful not to keep a reference to the popped future
                if timeout is None:
                    yield fs.pop().result()
                else:
                    yield fs.pop().result(end_time - time.monotonic())
        finally:
            for future in fs:
                future.cancel()
    return result_iterator()
```

This is where I get a little lost.

Are `mp.Pool` and `ProcessPoolExecutor` going down different rabbit holes? Is it possible to somehow get the "good stuff" from `ProcessPoolExecutor` by manually invoking `mp`/`Pool`/`map` with the correct parameters?

Comment: Your shown timings don't support your claim, `Pool.map()` takes less time. Btw, you can use `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` for using threads instead processes.

Comment: you're right, I'll have to recap what I had in work more accurately